# How to prevent the cell in a JTable from being null

Tags: java, jtable

I have a table with a custom table model which sets the classes of each column. If the user tries to enter a string in a number column then he/she will not be able to move on to the next cell. This is done automatically because I had specified the column types in the table model class. The problem is that in my program if the user deletes everything in the cell and presses tab to move on to the next cell I get the error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sweets.SP1$6.tableChanged(Main.java:1508)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(AbstractTableModel.java:275)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:667)
at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2740)
at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(JTable.java:4722)
at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(AbstractCellEditor.java:141)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.stopCellEditing(DefaultCellEditor.java:368)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor.stopCellEditing(DefaultCellEditor.java:233)
at javax.swing.JTable$GenericEditor.stopCellEditing(JTable.java:5467)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicTableUI.java:502)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1664)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2879)
at javax.swing.JTable.processKeyBinding(JTable.java:5258)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2940)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2842)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

How do I not allow the user to leave the cell as blank? or at least, if he/she pressed tab when the cell was empty then I would like the last proper value which was in the cell to be re-instantiated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link here: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/ shows a way to add a listener which should give you access to a cells old and new values once a cell's data has been changed. (You have to include a custom class which is also included on the site) If you can use that, then detect whenever a cell is changed, and if the new value is equal to null/empty prompt the user to enter some data, or just set the cell back to the old value.

**EDIT**

Something like the below may be what you want.  Remember to put the extra .java file somewhere on the Classpath

```
public class SO {
public static void main(String args[]) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Vector<String> rowOne = new Vector<String>();
rowOne.addElement("Bob");
rowOne.addElement("dave");
rowOne.addElement("Rowan");

Vector<String> rowTwo = new Vector<String>();
rowTwo.addElement("Jane");
rowTwo.addElement("Florence");
rowTwo.addElement("Heather");

Vector<String> rowThree = new Vector<String>();
rowThree.add("Star Wars");
rowThree.add("Darth Vader");
rowThree.add("Great White Shark");


Vector<Vector<String>> rowData = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
rowData.addElement(rowOne);
rowData.addElement(rowTwo);
rowData.addElement(rowThree);


Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
columnNames.addElement("Column One");
columnNames.addElement("Column Two");
columnNames.addElement("Column Three");  
table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);


//This is where the extra class comes in
Action action = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        TableCellListener tcl = (TableCellListener)e.getSource();
        if(tcl.getNewValue() == null || tcl.getNewValue().toString().trim().equals("")){
            table.getModel().setValueAt(tcl.getOldValue(), tcl.getRow(), tcl.getColumn());
        }
        System.out.println("Row   : " + tcl.getRow());
        System.out.println("Column: " + tcl.getColumn());
        System.out.println("Old   : " + tcl.getOldValue());
        System.out.println("New   : " + tcl.getNewValue());
    }
};
new TableCellListener(table, action);

frame.add(table);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(700, 240);
frame.setVisible(true);
  }

 private static JTable table;
 }
```

Good Luck!